# Laravel Valet is not working after installing redis

Tags: php, redis, valet

Just installed redis on the php that's used by valet.

Now all I get is the redis error. I even tried uninstalling valet and installing again. But this persists.

> ```
> valet restart
>
> Warning: Cannot load module "redis" because required module "igbinary" is not loaded in Unknown on line 0
> Could not open input file: 
> Warning: Cannot load module "redis" because required module "igbinary" is not loaded in Unknown on line 0/cli/valet.php
> ```

Comment: Fixed this by including igbinary.so in php.ini file.

Comment: I get this: "Warning: Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Could not open input file: 
Warning: Module "mongodb" is already loaded in Unknown on line 0/cli/valet.php" and do not have idea how to fix it.

Comment: @mrakodol may be valet is trying to load the mongodb twice. Have you tried removing it?